# Function in function refer to outer class

Tags: python

I've got the following piece of code which works:

```
class EngineCheck:
  class Config:
    IP = os.environ['SERVICE_IP']
    PORT = os.environ.get('SERVICE_PORT', 10051)

  def _request_all_(self):
    def _send_response(config: EngineCheck.Config):
      # do stuff
      return True
```

When defining the `_send_response` function, how can I avoid using the parent class name? So instead of `EngineCheck.Config`, I'd love to have something like `<parent/self/super()>.Config`.

Already tried using `super().Config` but it didn't work.

Comment: What's the _purpose_ of this, what's `_send_response` used for?

Comment: It's performing a call to an API endpoint but since I'm using it like 6 times in `_request_all()`, I thought that it would make sense to have it there. Obviously, I could move it outside the `_request_all()` function, but I have no use of it elsewhere.
The idea is that `_request_all()` performs some calls to some engines and, based on the response, `_send_response()` is used to send the status (response) of the calls to the "monitoring" endpoints.
My question is, can I somehow avoid using the outer class name in the definition of `_send_response()`?

Comment: Is there a reason that EngineCheck isn't a module instead? flat is better than nested.

Comment: I don't see how that would help. Kind of new to python so correct me if I'm wrong: I would have two classes, plain and simple, each with its own functions and stuff?

Comment: Why are you nesting the class? This does not create a parent/child relationship between the classes. The only effect you get from nesting a class is name-spacing. `super` makes *no sense here*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I had the impression that it would make sense. Much like the nested functions, if you use that function/class inside another function/class, doesn't it make sense to nest them?

Comment: So, the result of nesting is simply that to refer to the nested class, you must refer to the class that nests it, so in this case, you must use `Engine.Config`. *That is the whole purpose*: to force you to do that. If you don't want that (which is reasonable), there is no good reason to nest the classes. The nesting implies no other relationship between them. Note, the standard way organize your code into logically name-spaced units is to use *modules*.

Comment: As for functions, I do not think it makes sense to nest functions simply because one function is called in another. Even exclusively. Although in the case of functions, the considerations are different. When you nest classes, both classes gets evaluated once, at the same time. For functions, a nested function definition gets executed only when the nesting function is called (possibly every time it is called, which may be never). Ideally this is used when you want to change some aspected of the function that results from the nested function definition dynamically.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga understood. I know that I *should* use modules, but I thought that since that class only holds 2 values, it doesn't make sense to create a separate module. Might rethink that though.
Thank you for the explanation. Highly appreciated!

Comment: You don't want to create a seperate module! They should be in the same module.

Comment: So just have two classes, independent of each other then? That's the way to go?